# Selecting a tag base on another tag

Tags: xml, batch-file, xpath, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xmlstarlet

When i have an xml file like this (named `test.xml`):

```
<root>
<item val="3"></item>
<items>
  <item>1</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>3</item>
  <item>4</item>
  <item>5</item>
  <item>6</item>
</items>
</root>
```

I can do this:

`xmlstarlet sel -t -v /root/item/@val -o "," -v /root/items/item[3] test.xml` which results in the output `3,3`, which is OK. But when the value of /root/item/@val is changed then i do not want to change the command line for xmlstarlet.

How can i replace the `3` between the brackets for `/root/item/@val` ?

I tried: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v /root/item/@val -o "," -v /root/items/item[/root/item/@val] test.xml`

but that gives the following output:

```
3,1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I do have this problem on Windows, i could use `wsl` but a Windows solution is preferred ...

EDIT: Based on the suggestion from @Cyrus):

this batch file gives the correct result:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq" %%f in (`xml sel -t -v /root/item/@val  test.xml`) do set a=%%f
xml sel -t -o "%a%," -v /root/items/item[%a%]  test.xml
```

But it still do hope there is a single line version of this.

Comment: The ugly way with `bash` and command-substitution: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/root/item/@val' -o ',' -v "/root/items/item[$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/root/item/@val' file.xml)]" file.xml`

Comment: @Cyrus: sure that should work but i want to use this on Windows, and this will be a difficult thanks to Microsoft.

Comment: would `for /f "delims=" %%f in ('xml sel -t -v /root/item/@val  test.xml') do xml sel -t -o "%%f," -v /root/items/item[%%f]  test.xml` not make more sense? No need to set a variable.

Comment: @Gerhard: maybe, but i do not like toooooo long lines, thanks for the suggestion! (and they tend to be long when using xmlstarlet...)

Comment: What do you mean by too long lines? Setting a variable is an additional function, if the line seems too long, then drop a parenthesized code block and start a new line, anyway, was just a suggestion.

Comment: I do mean that, when i look at the line again in say 6 months time, i still need to understand what is happening. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `--var` to set a variable containing `@val` and compare that against the position of the `item`...

```
xmlstarlet sel -t --var val="/root/item/@val" -v "$val" -o "," -v "/root/items/item[number($val)]" test.xml
```

Another, slightly shorter, alternative to `/root/items/item[position()=$val]` above...

```
/root/items/item[number($val)]
```

Note: Using `number()` makes your original attempt work too:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v /root/item/@val -o "," -v /root/items/item[number(/root/item/@val)] test.xml
```

Example of Windows cmd usage:

[image]

Comment: I was looking for the function `number()`. The variant with `--var` is also very helpful! (/me placing the function at the start like this: `xmlstarlet sel -t --var val=number("/root/item/@val") -v "$val" -o "," -v "/root/items/item[$val]" test.xml`